# jquery autocomplete display complete list of items on focus

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I got the following code, which works fine except that I want the list of options to appear automatically when the cursor enters any field with class="bas".

Evyerthing works fine however I've tried several options and none do as expected.
The code below you need to press ALT+arrow down for the list to appear.
Using `$(this).autocomplete("search");` (which is what shows up in Google when I search for an answer) doesn't do anything.
using `$(this).autocomplete("search","");` also doesn't work.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong ???

```
$('.bas').each(function () {

                        var basis_options = [
                          { value: 'Spain', data: 'ES' },
                           { value: 'Italy', data: 'IT' },
                           { value: 'Portugal', data: 'PT' },
                           { value: 'Greece', data: 'GR' },
                           { value: 'Malta', data: 'MT' },

                        ];


                    var txt = $(this);
                    txt.autocomplete({
                        source: basis_options,
                        minLength: 0,
                        focus: function (event, ui) {      
                            $(this).trigger('focus.autocomplete');
                            //$(this).autocomplete("search"); <<< doesn't work
                        },
                       select: function ( event, ui ) { 
                            $(this).val( ui.item.data );                            
                       },
                       change: function () {
                            $(this).trigger("change");
                        }
                    });

                 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$(this).autocomplete("search");`

**try:**

`$(this).autocomplete("search", $(this).val());`

Comment: unfortunately your code doesn't do anything either...:(

Comment: Alright, it would be much easier to check if you could setup a quick Fiddle.

Comment: sorry, the page is done in asp.net, and I believe Fiddle doesn't work with asp.net. I've changed it to HTML but the code doesn't seem to work now, https://jsfiddle.net/ntej73y1/1/

Comment: Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ntej73y1/4/) now. This is how you want it, right?

Comment: thanks for the effort. It appears your Fiddle only shows the available values when you arrow down, once inside the box. I need it to show up as soon as the box has the focus. Also it appears you cannot use arrow up/down to select from list...if you try, it just takes the first available option.

Comment: Alright, check now [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ntej73y1/7/). This should work the way you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have found a solution to the problem, I hope this will help other people.
This code will aply to any textbox with csclass="bas" (change as requred)

As soon as you focus on the field, the list of available options appear. Just arrow up/down or click on the one you want.

In the example below, the user sees on the list the Country Name (eg: Spain) but once selected the Country Code (ES) is what actually fills the textbox.

I hope it helps other people...

```
$('.bas').each(function () {

                        var basis_options = [
                          { value: 'Spain', data: 'ES' },
                           { value: 'Italy', data: 'IT' },
                           { value: 'Portugal', data: 'PT' },
                           { value: 'Greece', data: 'GR' },
                           { value: 'Malta', data: 'MT' },

                        ];

var txt = $(this);
                        txt.autocomplete({
                            source: basis_options,
                            delay: 0,
                            minLength: 0,
                            select: function (event, ui) {$(this).val(ui.item.data); return false},
                            change: function (event, ui) {$(this).trigger("change")}
                        }).bind('focus', function () {
                            $(this).autocomplete("search");
                        })
```